# How to enable tapped effect in 'Grid' Windows 8 app development using C#/xaml?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8

how to give animation tapped effect when i click the grid..
It looks like tile and functions fine..
Do i have to change something in blend to make this happen?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are looking for a 'tilt' effect. This is not available out-of-the-box, but there are a number of solutions available online:

- http://www.sharpgis.net/post/2012/03/02/TiltEffect-for-Windows-8-Metro-XAML.aspx
- http://blog.thomaslebrun.net/2012/09/windows-8-how-to-add-tilt-effect-to-your-controls/

I think your best option is the 'Callisto' set of utilities:

https://github.com/timheuer/callisto

Comment: Colin: Thank you for replying.. But Callisto controls don't seem to work.. I installed Callisto from Nuget and added a reference in xaml page **xmlns:sg="using:Callisto.Controls"** and tried to add `<StackPanel sg:TiltEffect.IsTiltEnabled="True" />` but doesn't work.. It doesn't even identify TiltEffect class.. Strange..

Comment: your using statement is incorrect, needs the effects namespace, "using:Callisto.Effects". You can check the samples provided by callisto for this.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the correct syntax:
xaml reference->

```
xmlns:sg="using:Callisto.Controls"
```

and usage     ->

```
sg:Tilt.IsTiltEnabled="True"
```

Also check out:
https://github.com/timheuer/callisto/wiki/TiltEffect